MySQL DeadLock on Delete and Insert
in Laravel I have a service which is not wrapped in a transaction and involves both INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE and DELETE statements targeting the same table, customers.
INSERT INTO customers (columns...) VALUES (values...) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...;
delete from customers where customers.id in (103,112,114,119,121...).
into a single MySQL database.
When I trigger multiple requests to these endpoints simultaneously, I encounter deadlocks. I understand that INSERT and DELETE operations should lock the data rows they affect, and the next transaction should wait until these locks are released.
I'm facing deadlocks even though these operations are not wrapped around a DB transaction statement.
Can anyone explain why DELETE and INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE operations cause deadlocks and how to prevent these deadlocks?

Waiting for a lock amd deadlocks are two different things. Deadlock means that two transactions mutually lock something the other transaction needs to proceed, so neither can. Mysql chooses one of the two and rolls that transaction back. All data modification statements run in a tranasaction in innodb, even if you have not explicitly created one.

so, deadlock only occurs when I use Transactions right?

See the last sentence of my previous comment: All data modification statements run in a tranasaction in innodb, even if you have not explicitly created one.

Bill Karwin's answer to the duplicate question explains the difference between deadlocks and lock waits. Also explains how to get more information on both of these.
